# Java delete single file from GridFS

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

Is there a way to delete a single file without the objedId in GridFS?

I just found this on MongoDB:

```
objectId fileId; //ObjectId of a file uploaded to GridFS
gridFSBucket.delete(fileId);
```

But I don't know how to query all the objectId's to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
GridFSFindIterable gridFSFile = gridFSBucket.find(eq("filename",listOfFiles.get(i).getName()));
// listOfFiles are a list which contains the names
gridFSBucket.delete(gridFSFile.cursor().next().getId());
```

I hope it is helpful.